# how to save html structure, deconstruct it and show it inside in a number of generated divs with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

Let's say we have the following structure (that we can't control) it always has a strong tag:

```
<body>
    <p><strong>First title</strong></p>
    <p>One paragraph</p>

    <p><strong>Second title</strong></p>
    <p>One paragraph</p>
    <p>One paragraph</p>

    <p><strong>Third</strong></p>
    <p>One paragraph</p>
    <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
    </ul>

    <p><strong>Fourth Title</strong></p>
    <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

How would copy/display the content in separate divs (**each div would contain the content between the first strong element, and the second one.**).The strong content would go above each new div (as a separate div)

like this::

```
   <div>
       <p><strong>First title</strong></p>
   </div>
   <div>
        <p>One paragraph</p>
   </div>


    <div>
        <p><strong>Second title</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>One paragraph</p>
        <p>One paragraph</p>
    </div>
    
    
    <div>
        <p><strong>Third title</strong></p>
    </div>
     <div>
        <p>One paragraph</p>
        <ul>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    
    <div>
        <p><strong>Fourth title</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>something</li>
            <li>something</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I tried looping with `querySelectorAll ("body > *")`, but what happens is it works if there's only one paragraph or one ul (if I have more than that, I get a new block, and everything shifts). Basically, titles (in outside div) are not synced with the content, if the content has more than one element.

```
 let getTitle = document.querySelectorAll("strong");

const removeTitle = document.querySelectorAll("strong");
    removeTitle.forEach((item) => item.remove());

       const Content = document.querySelectorAll("body > * ");
    
    
            for (i = 0; i < Content.length; i++) {
    
            }
```

My understanding is, I am currently looping over each element, instead of blocks with a start and end, where the "strong" tag is a delimiter.

Any ideas how to go about this problem?

Comment: is this as simple as surrounding all your `<p>` and `<ul>` tags with `<div>`s?

Comment: Maybe I'm complicating, but yeah, I would be like to be able too loop through (in the case of the example) three blocks of content. Where the "strong" tag dictates where the delimination is. The number of strong paragraphs is dynamic. Based on what is pasted in.